Some guys steal drug from a house an they get chased, one guy was always cleaning his gun
This is what I can remember:

They break into a house (as a prank I believe) but surprisingly it was some sort of safe house or something, so they kill the people inside and steal the drugs (and possibly money too)
They start selling the drug but the original owners realize they are selling the drug (I believe in a bar toilet), so the guys start getting chased by the drug traffickers 
I remember one of the guys was like introverted and was always cleaning his gun, in a scene after killing some of the chasers in a very impressive way, he puts his gun in his mouth (or head) and kills himself.
I saw it between 1996 and 1999 on tv so the release date may have been earlier.

That's all I can remember.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I know this movie and can't find it either. It wasn't a prank exactly, they were like owing money to the mob and decide to rob the mob's place and pay them with their own money. And I also remember the movie because of the guy that killed himself. He wasn't part of the team, but decides to help them, practicaly the raid is seccessful because he awesomly kill few men and saves those two main protagonists. I think there was one bigger name as cameo in the movie, like Paul Sorvino. I checked his movies and didn't find this one.
